# pass 2-d arrays with different names to one function

Tags: visual-c++

How can i pass 2-d arrays with different names (but the same structure and data type and size) to a function?

```
using namespace std;

void OutputArray ();
int A[4][2] = {{1, 2} , {3, 4} , { 5, 7} , {8, 1} };
int B[4][2] = {{5, 6} , {7, 8} , { 3, 9} , {2, 2} };

int main ()
{

    OutputArray(A[][2]);
    OutputArray(B[][2]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;  
}

void OutputArray(int intNumbersArray[][2])
{
    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 4 ; intCounter++)
    {
    cout << outputArray[intCounter][0] << outputArray[intCounter][1] << endl;
    }   

}
```

and consequently have the printed A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fixing some bugs i got this code to work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void OutputArray (int intNumbersArray[][2]);
int A[4][2] = {{1, 2} , {3, 4} , { 5, 7} , {8, 1} };
int B[4][2] = {{5, 6} , {7, 8} , { 3, 9} , {2, 2} };

void OutputArray(int intNumbersArray[][2])
{
    int intCounter = 0;
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 4 ; intCounter++)
    {
    cout << intNumbersArray[intCounter][0] << intNumbersArray[intCounter][1] << endl;
    }   

}

int main ()
{

    OutputArray(A);
    OutputArray(B);

    cin;
    return 0;  
}
```

- you needed `#include <iostream>` for `sin` and `cout`
- you needed the signature of `OutputArray` to contain the parameter `int intNumbersArray[][2]`
- you needed to pass only `A` and `B` and not `A[][2]` `B[][2]`
- In function `OutputArray` you used `outputArray` and not `intNumbersArray` which is the array you meant